# Django: SQL Injection - Use subquery in raw query

Tags: python, django

I'm getting an error when I try to pass a non-executed query string into a raw query, using the **params** argument that [Django recommends](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw), to use as a subquery:

```
from apps.bikeshare.models import Station
qs = Station.objects.filter(...)

subquery_string = qs.values('id').order_by().query
raw = Station.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM bikeshare_station WHERE id IN (%s)', [subquery_string])
```

The query prints the correct SQL (`WHERE` clause omitted):

```
<RawQuerySet: SELECT * FROM bikeshare_station WHERE id IN (SELECT "bikeshare_station"."id" FROM "bikeshare_station" WHERE ...)>
```

However, executing the raw query (`raw[0]`) gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2847, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-6eada3e31b4e>", line 1, in <module>
    raw[0]
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1329, in __getitem__
    return list(self)[k]
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1299, in __iter__
    query = iter(self.query)
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 93, in __iter__
    self._execute_query()
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 127, in _execute_query
    self.cursor.execute(self.sql, params)
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/gbrown/Envs/bikeshare-dev/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Query'
```

I'm aware that this is dangerous as it is SQL injection. However, I would like to support this, to create a QuerySet method (which happens to require raw query) that can be used on the end of a queryset chain where the filtered queryset is passed into the raw query as a subquery.

Would the **params** parameter mitigate any risk even if the error didn't happen? Or shall I just allow the risk and use basic python string formatting?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `query_set.filter(id__in=your_list_of_ids)` somewhere?

Comment: @JonClements thanks, just realised I had another issue too, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just released my method doesn't work properly anyway, since the `query` method doesn't return valid SQL, i.e.

```
qs = Station.objects.filter(name='Albert Gate, Hyde Park').values('id').order_by()
print(qs.query)

[out] SELECT "bikeshare_station"."id" FROM "bikeshare_station" WHERE "bikeshare_station"."name" = Albert Gate, Hyde Park
```

blows up because the name string is not quoted.

It seems the only way then is, as [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) points out in his comment, to execute the query and pass in a list of ids which can be achieved:

```
qs = Station.objects.filter(name='Albert Gate, Hyde Park')
ids = list(qs.values_list('id', flat=True))
```

You could then pass the list of ids to the raw query rather than a string.

Comment: Out of curiosity - I'm still not sure what you were trying to do here? Query names that were also in a subset of IDs, or get a list of IDs matching a name and then get a raw ORM'd generated SQL from it or... ? Just wondering where the `.raw` stuff comes into this is all...

Comment: @JonClements see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49862662/5221078) to another question. I was trying to terminate a queryset chain ending in a raw query. I wanted to pass the query "as is" as a subquery in the raw query to give maximum flexibility. However, since the SQL returned by `query` isn't valid I can't rely on that anyway.